# Replace string inside curvy brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

I would need to replace the strings contained within the curved brackets with the same strings but with an initial prefix and curly brackets **\fill{(*test_string*)}**. Is this possible?
Example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.
(first_string)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.
(second_string)
```

Transform in:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.
\fill{(first_string)}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore.
\fill{(second_string)}
```

Comment: learn regular expression search replace

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am interested in understanding and learning. Any useful links?

Comment: read the MDN pages on Regex, they deal with the JavaScript dialect used by VSC, there are tons of webpages about regex, read SO posts with tag `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you could use a regex search and replace. A simple example of this can be found [here](https://dev.to/rfornal/vs-code-search-and-replace-regex-mn2).  In your case, this should work:

[image: image of regex used to find the string to replace]

The regular expression `\(([^\)]+)\)` does the following (as taken from [this site](https://regex101.com/) - you'll need to paste the regex into the site to see the explanation):

> - `\(` matches the character literally (case sensitive)
> - 1st Capturing Group `([^\)]+)`
>
>   - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\)]`
>
>     - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>     - `\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)
> - `\)` matches the character `)`  literally (case sensitive)

In Visual Studio Code, if you enable regex search by clicking the `.*` icon in the search bar, you can put this regular expression in.  Then, in the replace section, you can put `\fill{($1)}` where the `$1` is the *1st Capturing Group* mentioned previously (the `first_string`, `second_string`, etc. part found by the regular expression).

There are a lot of Regex posts here on Stackoverflow you may want to read.  One notable one is [Greedy versus Lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: You can use the simpler `(\(.+?\))` and replace with `\fill{$1}`.   The greedy `?`  simplifies it.  And it is worth mentioning that nested `()` with a string is a big problem for a regex to solve.